# SpringBoot RestTemplate exchange having issue with ParameterizedTypeReference conversion for ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, netflix-eureka

I am building two microservices which are supposed to talk to each other.
I am using Eureka as service registry.

**Microservice 1** - 
*Microservice1.java*

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Microservice1Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Microservice1Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

*Microservice1Controller.java*

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/getdata")
public class Microservice1Controller {  
    @GetMapping(value = "/") 
public ResponseEntity<Microservice1ResponseWrapper<List<Customer1>>> getAll() {
        List<Customer1> list = //get data from repository

        return new ResponseEntity<Microservice1ResponseWrapper<List<Customer1>>>(new Microservice1ResponseWrapper<List<Customer1>>(Microservice1ResponseStatus.SUCCESS,list);
    }
}
```

*Microservice1ResponseWrapper.java* - this is generic wrapper

```
public class Microservice1ResponseWrapper<T> {
private Microservice1ResponseStatus status;
private T data;
//constructor, getter and setters
}
```

*applicationProperties.yaml*

```
spring:
  application:
    name: microservice1

server:
  port: 8073
```

**Microservice2**
Microservice2 that will get data from Microservice1

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Microservice2Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Microservice2Application.class, args);
    }
}

@Configuration
class Config {

    @LoadBalanced
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

*Microservice2Controller.java*

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/fetchdata")
public class Microservice2Controller {  
@Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;


    @GetMapping(value = "/")
public ResponseEntity<Microservice2ResponseWrapper<List<Customer2>>> getAll() {     
            String getAllUrl = "http://microservice1/getdata/";
            ParameterizedTypeReference<Microservice2ResponseWrapper<List<Customer2>>>  parameterizedTypeReference = 
                    new ParameterizedTypeReference<Microservice2ResponseWrapper<List<Customer2>>>(){};

            ResponseEntity<Microservice2ResponseWrapper<List<Customer2>>> listData =
                    restTemplate.exchange(getAllUrl, HttpMethod.GET, null,parameterizedTypeReference);          
            return listData;
    }   
}
```

*Microservice2ResponseWrapper.java* - this is generic wrapper

```
public class Microservice2ResponseWrapper<T> {
private Microservice2ResponseStatus status;
private T data;
//constructor, getter and setters
}
```

*applicationProperties.yaml*

```
spring:
  application:
    name: microservice2

server:
  port: 8074
```

Customer1(in Microservice1) and Customer2(Microservice2) are almost identical objects.

```
public class Customer1 implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long custId;

    private String custName;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private Long age;

    public Customer1() {
    }

    public Customer1(String custName, String firstName, String lastName, Long age) {
        this.custName = custName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Customer1(Long custId, String custName, String firstName, String lastName, Long age) {
        this.custId = custId;
        this.custName = custName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }

//getter, setter and toString
}
```

Customer2.java in Microservice2

```
public class Customer2 implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long custId;

    private String custName;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private Long age;

    public Customer2() {
    }

//getter, setter and toString
}
```

When I  run Microservice1 : http://localhost:8073/getdata it gets data from database and works fine. Here is the response I see on screen:

```
<Microservice1ResponseWrapper>
<status>SUCCESS</status>
<data>
<custId>1</custId>
<custName>string1</custName>
<firstName>string1</firstName>
<lastName>string1</lastName>
<age>30</age>
</data>
</Microservice1ResponseWrapper>
```

When I  run Microservice2 : http://localhost:8074/fetchdata it should go to Microservice 1 and get data.

However, I am getting error like:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:994)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:977)

Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.rest.Customer2` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('1'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.rest.Customer2` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('1')
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 61] (through reference chain: com.rest.wrapper.Microservice2ResponseWrapper["data"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:245)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:227)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:102)
    ... 77 more

Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.rest.Customer2` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('1')
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 61] (through reference chain: com.rest.wrapper.Microservice2ResponseWrapper["data"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1343)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1032)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator._createFromStringFallbacks(ValueInstantiator.java:371)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromString(StdValueInstantiator.java:323)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromString(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1373)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:171)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:161)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:286)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:245)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:27)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:127)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:369)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3084)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:239)
```

***Am I making any mistake in ParameterizedTypeReference or resttemplate exchange call?***

NOTE: If I run these two microservices without Eureka registry, they work absolutely fine. But the moment I introduce Eureka and register these two services with Eureka, I get issue as stated above.
For this I just made the change to Miroservice2 controller:
String getAllUrl = "http://localhost:8073/getdata/";

---

Update - 02/22/19

here's what I tried

updated Microservice1Controller-getAll()as below:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/") 
public ResponseEntity<List<Customer1>> getAll() {
        List<Customer1> list = //get data from repository

        return new ResponseEntity<List<Customer1>>(list);
    }
```

Updated Microservice2Controller- getAll() method

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/")
public ResponseEntity<List<Customer2>> getAll() {     
            String getAllUrl = "http://microservice1/getdata/";
            ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Customer2>>  parameterizedTypeReference = 
                    new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Customer2>>(){};

            ResponseEntity<List<Customer2>> listData =
                    restTemplate.exchange(getAllUrl, HttpMethod.GET, null,parameterizedTypeReference);          
            return listData;
    }
```

This worked fine-  call Microservice1 from Microservice2 as stated in earlier description.
Microservice1 returning ResponseEntity> to Microservice2 and Microservice2 converting that to ResponseEntity>.

However, 
Microservice1 returning `ResponseEntity<Microservice1ResponseWrapper<List<Customer1>>>` to Microservice2 and Microservice2 can't be able to convert to `ResponseEntity<Microservice2ResponseWrapper<List<Customer2>>>`.

---

UPDATE 06/28/19

If I make following change in Microservice2 Controller then I see 2 issues:

1. start getting LinkedHashMap error.
   java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.util.List
2. It doesn't pull all records, it just pulls last element from List. e.g. There are 2 users, then it just shows last one user and not all.

> ```
> ParameterizedTypeReference<Microservice2ResponseWrapper>  parameterizedTypeReference = 
>                       new ParameterizedTypeReference<Microservice2ResponseWrapper>(){};
>
> ResponseEntity<Microservice2ResponseWrapper> listData =
>                       restTemplate.exchange(getAllUrl, HttpMethod.GET, null,parameterizedTypeReference);
> List ls = (List) listData.getBody().getData();
>
> //if I print listData.getBody().getData() then it just shows only one record of users.
> ```

Comment: can you show the JSON response and also do you get error for both microservices? or only for second one?

Comment: When I call just microservice1 I get response. Please check above description. i had shared response I see on screen. I am getting error while calling microservice1 from microservice2. I updated error message with JSON response. Pleas check that.

Comment: Can you please update the customer1 and customer2 classes @Shivraj

Comment: @Deadpool Updated both classes. Also please check "Note" at the end of description. I see error only when these two services are registered with Eureka. Without Eureka they work fine.  Also I noticed when working with Eureka response I see as XML(already attached in description) and without Eureka I see response as JSON. I am not explicitly making any changes to have it run that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't able to resolve it using RestTemplate. So I went ahead with alternative of using Open Feign.

Step 1. in pom.xml I added dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-openfeign-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Step 2. Add client interface

```
@FeignClient(name = "microservice1")
public interface Microservice1Client {
 @GetMapping(value = "/getdata/") 
 ResponseEntity<Microservice1ResponseWrapper<List<Customer1>>> getAll();
}
```

Step 3. in Microservice2Controller inject FeignClient bean Microservice1Client

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/fetchdata")
public class Microservice2Controller {  
@Autowired
Microservice1Client microservice1Client;

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
public ResponseEntity<Microservice2ResponseWrapper<List<Customer2>>> getAll() {     
            return microservice1Client.getAll();          
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a default constructor for Customer2 class.
Customer2(){}

Comment: Tried this. But didn't work. Please see description: I have added both classes Customer1 and Customer2. Also please have a look at "NOTE" section at the end of description.